# proof the union of an infinetly countable set and an element is aslo countable

Tags: real-analysis

If a set $A$ is a countably infinite and b $\notin$ $A$, then $A$ $\cup$ {b} is also countable.

I think that by assuming that the union is countable then $A$ is a subset of a countable set. thus it's true. however I feel this is wrong. Is there a better way to prove it. or how do I do my proof step by step.

Comment: One good way to think of a countably infinite set is that it can be listed. (i.e. every integer eventually appears on the list $0,1,-1,2,-2,3,-3\ldots$) Knowing that such a list exists for the elements of $A$, try to construct a list of the elements in $A\cup \{ b \}$

Comment: The argument you sketched would show that if $A \cup \{b\}$ is countable, then $A$ is countable. But you need to show the reverse implication: if $A$ is countable, then $A \cup \{b\}$ is countable. Hint: $b, a_1, a_2 ,a_3, \ldots$

Comment: Think for one second what you are saying.  You are assuming what you need to prove, demonstrating that if what you need to prove then a hypothesis that we are given as true would be true, and declaring ourselves done.  This is like being asked to prove, this is like being asked to prove if trump runs, he will win and claiming: Assume trump wins, that means he is running.  Done.

Comment: Every hear the problem of the infinite hotel? If A is countable there is a bijection $\phi$ from A to N.  Let $\phi'(a) = \phi (a)+1; \phi'(b)=1$.  Then $\phi'$ is a bijection from the union to the natural numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to show that $A\cup \{b\}$ is countably infinite is by defining a bijection $f:\Bbb{N}\to A\cup \{b\}$.

Now, since $A$ is countably infinite, there exist $g:\Bbb{N}\to A$ which is bijective. Let's call $g(1)=a_1, g(2)=a_2,...,g(n)=a_{n},..$ So lets define $f$ in the following way: 
$$f(1)=b, f(2)=a_1,...,f(n)=g(n+1)=a_{n+1},...$$ and let's see that $f$ is in fact bijective.

Surjective:

We already know that $f(1)=b$, so let's take $a\in A$. Since $g$ is bijective, there exist $n\in \Bbb{N}$ such that $f(n)=a_n=a$. But by definition, $g(n+1)=f(n)=a$ and of course $n+1 \in \Bbb{N}$.

Injective:

Take $n,m \in \Bbb{N}$ such that $m \neq n$ then if both $m,n \neq 1$ then:

$g(n)=f(n-1)\neq f(m-1)=g(m)$ since $f$ is bijective.

Now if $m=1$ and $n \neq 1$ then $f(1)=b \neq f(n)=a_{n-1}$ for every $n\geq 2$ since $b \notin A$. (The case $n=1$ and $m \neq 1$ is of course analogous).

Therefore $g$ is bijective and therefore $A \cup \{b\}$ is countably infinite

Comment: To Jake : Think of g(1),g(2),... as a "count"  of the members of A, Now put b at the head of the line, and count again :  f(1)=b, f(2)=g(1),f(3)=g(2),...

Answer (score 0):

You made a logical mistake. Assuming something true and getting a true result just tell you that your assumption is consistent in that way. Actually you need to check every connection to other truths to precisely say that your assumption is consistent. 
 With consistency you can define new things onto others. If you don't define it, then everything is still fine.
 However proving means showing that it must be true because of other known truths. One of the famous way of doing this is assuming something true and getting a false result, implies that your assumption is inconsistent, that is it can't be true with other known truths and it must be false.